# Xcode 7.1 - libicucore.dylib (No such file or directory)

Tags: ios, xcode, build, xcode7, archive

I'm using Xcode 7.1 and I have a project that was build with an early version of Xcode.
When I build and test the app in the simulator everything is fine, but when I try to Archive the project I got an error.

I set Generic iOS Device, try to build an get this message:

```
Libtool /Users/inalambrik/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/QR_App-bazrfzfvzmearxfmexfpkknhtynu/Build/Intermediates/ParseKit.build/Debug-iphoneos/libParseKitMobile.build/Objects-normal/arm64/libParseKitMobile.a normal arm64
    cd "/Users/inalambrik/Documents/XCode Projects/Buysmart/Frameworks/Third Party/ParseKit"
    export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=5.0
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool -static -arch_only arm64 -syslibroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS9.1.sdk -L/Users/inalambrik/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/QR_App-bazrfzfvzmearxfmexfpkknhtynu/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -filelist /Users/inalambrik/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/QR_App-bazrfzfvzmearxfmexfpkknhtynu/Build/Intermediates/ParseKit.build/Debug-iphoneos/libParseKitMobile.build/Objects-normal/arm64/ParseKitMobile.LinkFileList -framework Foundation /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS9.1.sdk/usr/lib/libicucore.dylib -o /Users/inalambrik/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/QR_App-bazrfzfvzmearxfmexfpkknhtynu/Build/Intermediates/ParseKit.build/Debug-iphoneos/libParseKitMobile.build/Objects-normal/arm64/libParseKitMobile.a

error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: can't open file: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS9.1.sdk/usr/lib/libicucore.dylib (No such file or directory)
```

I can't find the file `libicucore.dylib` on the mac.
Why can I build with a simulator, but can't when I try to Archive?

Answer (score 2):

Xcode 7.1 changed the name of some libraries now it uses .tdb files.

Remove the libicucore.dylib and replace it with libicucore.tdb you will find it searching inside Linked Frameworks and Libraries in the general tab of your target.