# How to create CakePHP project (previous version) using Composer (using an old version of PHP, in 2023)

Tags: docker, macos, cakephp-3.0, php-7.4

TL;DR Technology moving on and what was deprecated is obsolete now. But fear not, Docker here to solve the problem. See the answer below to see how I create a CakePHP 3.6 project on macOS Ventura.

---

Here, in 2023, I have my Mac updated to Ventura (13.0.1) with brew installed (Homebrew 3.6.18) and I have this requirement to create a CakePHP project, specifically version 3.6 (I am very well aware of [CakePHP 3.x End of Support](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/releases/tag/3.10.5) - *but life happens*). Now the scene was set, let's go and rock-and-roll!
Heading to [installation documentation](https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/installation.html) yields these;

1. Install PHP - per documentation PHP 7.4 is supported, yay (*sort of*)
2. Install Composer - there is at least one another alternative, the Oven way, but I haven't tried it
3. Create a CakePHP Project

OK, let me install PHP. Oh, I already PHP installed via brew, PHP 8.2.1. Good then let me check if I already have Composer installed as well, `composer --version`; yes "Composer version 2.4.4 2022-10-27 14:39:29". So the last thing I need to do is to Create a CakePHP Project. Let me run `composer create-project --prefer-dist cakephp/app:"^3.6" my_app_name`;

```bash
Creating a "cakephp/app:^3.6" project at "./my_app_name"
Info from https://repo.packagist.org: #StandWithUkraine
Installing cakephp/app (3.10.1)
  - Installing cakephp/app (3.10.1): Extracting archive
Created project in /Users/johndoe/Code/my_app_name
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - cakephp/cakephp[3.10.0, ..., 3.10.5] require php >=5.6.0,<8.0.0 -> your php version (8.2.1) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - Root composer.json requires cakephp/cakephp 3.10.* -> satisfiable by cakephp/cakephp[3.10.0, ..., 3.10.5].
```

Oh, noes . Well, let me downgrade my PHP version, or better yet let brew install PHP 7.4 side-by-side (*actually it was not a "better yet"*). Quick Googling yield [Update PHP to 7.4 macOS Catalina with brew](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64684713/update-php-to-7-4-macos-catalina-with-brew) on SO. Hmm, I'm on Venture and this is for Catalina. But there is one comment;

> This solution works perfectly in MacOS BigSur.
>
> -[juanitourquiza](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2400373/juanitourquiza)

I took juanitourquiza's word for it, besides there's nothing to lose... Except for those irritating "libicuio.71.dylib no such file" errors. It turned out that ["Xcode 7.1 changed the name of some libraries now it uses .tdb files."](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33512877/250453). Bummer!

There I was scratching my head, I thought to myself "well I'm already going to use Docker to serve the app anyway (locally), why not use Docker to create the project too?".

Comment: Would you be kind enough to take a moment to tell why you gave -1?

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost you have to have Docker installed, and *how* is another story.

#### Create a CakePHP Project - Take 2

Next this little command would suffice to create a CakePHP 3.6 project;

```bash
docker run -it --rm \
    --name php74_composer \
    -v "$PWD":/usr/src/myapp \
    -w /usr/src/myapp \
    php:7.4-cli sh -c "pwd; apt-get update && apt-get install -y unzip; \
        curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/composer/getcomposer.org/76a7060ccb93902cd7576b67264ad91c8a2700e2/web/installer | php; \
        php composer.phar create-project --no-install --no-interaction --no-scripts --prefer-dist cakephp/app:\"3.6.5\" my_app_name; \
        cd my_app_name; \
        php ../composer.phar config --no-plugins allow-plugins.cakephp/plugin-installer true; \
        php ../composer.phar install --ignore-platform-reqs; \
        php ../composer.phar run --no-interaction post-install-cmd; \
        cd ../ && rm composer.phar; \
        exit"
```

Although it's highly opinionated about the versions (PHP 7.4 and CakePHP 3.6.5) it does the trick! When you run it, it'll create a directory called "my_app_name" on the current working directory. After the container exit out you may move this directory anywhere as your heart desire.

#### Serve the App

As I mentioned I am going to use Docker as well to serve the app (locally). There are trillion tutorials out there showing how to do it, nonetheless here's my solution;

```bash
# In the "my_app_name" directory

mkdir docker && cd docker

echo "FROM php:7.4-fpm

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \\
    libicu-dev \\
    git \\
    curl \\
    zip \\
    unzip

RUN docker-php-ext-configure intl
RUN docker-php-ext-install intl
RUN docker-php-ext-enable intl

RUN docker-php-ext-configure pdo_mysql
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql
RUN docker-php-ext-enable pdo_mysql

RUN curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/composer/getcomposer.org/76a7060ccb93902cd7576b67264ad91c8a2700e2/web/installer | php && \\
    mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer

WORKDIR /var/www" > Dockerfile

echo "version: '3.8'

services:
  app:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: johndoes-app
    restart: always
    working_dir: /var/www
    volumes:
      - ../:/var/www

  nginx:
    image: nginx:1.23-alpine
    container_name: johndoes-nginx
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8000:80
    volumes:
      - ../:/var/www
      - ./nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d
" > docker-compose.yml

mkdir nginx && cd nginx

echo "server {
    listen 80;
    index index.php;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_page 404 /index.php;
    root /var/www/webroot;
    location ~ \.php {
        try_files \$uri =404;
        fastcgi_pass app:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME \$document_root\$fastcgi_script_name;
    }
    location / {
        try_files \$uri \$uri/ /index.php?\$query_string;
    }
}
" > nginx.conf
```

And then at "my_app_name/docker" run `docker-compose up`. After services started go to "http://localhost:8000".

Now you may proceed with [configuring](https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/development/configuration.html) your app. Cheers.

---

#### Update for Xdebug

If you wish to debug your app via VSCode / VSCodium running on your host machine (Mac in my case);

1. Append the following to `Dockerfile` (in between existing lines denoted);

   ```
   # existing RUN docker-php-ext-enable pdo_mysql

   RUN pecl install xdebug-3.1.6 && docker-php-ext-enable xdebug

   # existing RUN curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/composer/getcomposer.org/...
   ```
2. Append the following to `docker-compose.yml` (in between existing lines denoted);

   ```
   # for "app" service
   # existing - ../:/var/www
   - ./99-xdebug.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini
   # mind indentation since this is a YAML file, i.e.;
   # dashes must be on the same level vertically
   ```
3. Create the INI file for Xdebug;

   ```bash
   # at the docker directory
   echo "zend_extension = xdebug
   xdebug.mode = debug
   xdebug.start_with_request = yes
   xdebug.client_host = host.docker.internal" > 99-xdebug.ini
   ```
4. Install the PHP Debug extension [for VSCode](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=xdebug.php-debug) or [for VSCodium](https://open-vsx.org/extension/felixfbecker/php-debug).
5. As the final step have a `.vscode/launch.json` file including these;

   ```json
   {
     "name": "Listen for Xdebug",
     "type": "php",
     "request": "launch",
     "port": 9003,
     "pathMappings": {
       "/var/www": "${workspaceFolder}"
     }
   }
   ```

   `"pathMappings"` is the crucial setting here, others were automatically generated.

Comment: If you have MySQL installed on the host machine and would like to connect to it within Dockerized CakePHP app like me, use `host.docker.internal` as the hostname for the datasource configuration.